# Contact Cards disappear while I create them

Tags: contacts.app

I have used "Contacts" for years. But now when I try to add cards, they disappear as I am filling them out. Using OS 10.13.2 on Macbook Pro.

Comment: This has been reported before.  I checked mine and it happens to me too. No answer to the previous question. Maybe your question will get noticed more.

Comment: Just now I added a contact successfully by adding it to my iPhone and letting the icloud sync do its work. Nice to have a work around, but this takes a lot longer when I am adding a dozen contacts.

Comment: Thanks for info though. i appreciate knowing there is a work around.